# HTML XML to Excel via PHP - Convert to Number

Tags: php, html, xml, excel, ms-office

I am trying to convert html to excel without using any library.

I just encountered one problem.... I have the classes ready etc etc (basically I exported an excel to html) and is now doing it vice versa [just changing the content].

I am formatting my currency/totals as numbers with 2 decimals. (when you right click them it says so at least) but in the excel it still shows as a Text and in order to work with them it requires me to press Convert to Number

At the moment I have this in my loop. Do you think its enough ?

```
<td class=xl112 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2,033.00
</td>
```

and in the css I have

```
.xl112
    {mso-style-parent:style0;
    mso-number-format:"\#\,\#\#0\.00_ \;\[Red\]\\-\#\,\#\#0\.00\\ ";
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-top:.5pt solid windowtext;
    border-right:1.0pt solid windowtext;
    border-bottom:.5pt solid windowtext;
    border-left:1.0pt solid windowtext;
    background:#FFFF99;
    mso-pattern:auto none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  Not sure why you have those backslashes in your number format style?

See here:  http://codesnipers.com/?q=excel-compatible-html

Full reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477(office.10).aspx

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
      xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <style>
        .s1 {mso-number-format:"#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00";}
    </style>
</head>



 <body>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="s1" x:num="2033">2033</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using HTML as the "excel" file - everything in HTML is automatically text. This is especially true when you're "pretty printing" your numbers with thousands separators.

If you want your numbers treated as numbers, use a real Excel file, generated by [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). There you specify EXACTLY what the data type in a cell is. You say you don't want to use a library, but you'd be better off if you actually did.

Comment: you are right I should use PHPEXcel but I cannot since its a standard from where I work so I have to stick to the traditional way